# Python: get item from set based on key

Tags: python

I have a class with a custom hash method.

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key # key is unique
        self.value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        # 'value' is unhashable, so return the hash of 'key'
        return hash(self.key)
```

I make a `set` using objects of this class.

```
t0, t1, t2 = Test(0, 10), Test(1, 5), Test(2, 10)
s = set([t0, t1, t2])
```

Now, is there any way to find objects from `s` using `key`? i.e. I want to do:

```
find_using_key(s, 1) # should return [t1]
```

I know I can do this by iterating over the items in the set, but I feel like there should be an O(1) method to do this since `key` effectively determines the 'position' in the `set`.

Comment: Could you explain why you can't use a dictionary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ... since key effectively determines the 'position' in the set

That's not really true. Two elements with the same `key` can coexist in the set:

```
>>> t0, t1 = Test(1,1), Test(1,2)
>>> len(set((t0,t1)))
2
```

The hash value does not define equality. That would also not be possible, because you can have hash collisions.

Now as for your question: Don't use a `set`. It is defined by an abstract interface with the operations *insert* and *find*. It does not provide the operation you want. Whether a potential underlying implementation could theoretically support the operation you want is not really relevant. Instead, use a `dict`, and associate the keys with the instances.

Comment: No, it can be assumed that the key is unique(I'll edit the question). Morover, in 'traditional' hash tables, it is possible to get a list of items that share a hash value.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: You are confusing something here: `set` is just an interface, a collection of operations like *insert* and *find*. It doesn't provide any more than that. Whether it is implemented using a hash table or not is up to the implementation

Comment: The downvoter might please want to have a look at the revision of my answer, which does not include the admittedly questionable part that was present in one of the earlier versions :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to use sets, you can get `O(1)` lookup using dict.  Just use your key as the key for the dict items:

```
d = {}
d[t0.key] = t0
d[t1.key] = t1
d[t2.key] = t2
```

You can use dict comprehension to make it cleaner:

```
d = {t.key: t for t in [t0,t1,t2]}
```

or in 2.6:

```
d = dict((t.key,t) for t in [t0,t1,t2])
```